# Doctrine : 2 leftJoin on same table, but different Join::WITH

Tags: doctrine-orm

i got a request with 2 leftJoin on the same table, with different alias :

```
$qb2->leftJoin('d2.groupeDossiers', 'gd',Join::WITH, 'gd.type = \'assure\'');
$qb2->leftJoin('d2.groupeDossiers', 'gdt',Join::WITH, 'gdt.type = \'tiers\'');
```

But it seems there's conflicts. How could i do that leftJoin in a single request ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

### Without using Doctrine Relationships

If your relationship is like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupeDossier", mappedBy="test")
 */
private $groupeDossiers;
```

And

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="groupeDossier")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_test", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $test;
```

The best way to return what you want is :

```
$qb2->select('MyBundle:Test','t');
$qb2->addSelect('gd');
$qb2->addSelect('gdt');
$qb2->leftJoin('MyBundle:GroupeDossiers', 'gd',Join::WITH, 'gd.type = \'assure\' AND gd.test = t');
$qb2->leftJoin('MyBundle:GroupeDossiers', 'gdt',Join::WITH, 'gdt.type = \'tiers\' AND gdt.test = t');
```

But then, you should use `getArrayResult()` to get `gd` dans `gdt`

### With Doctrine Relationships -- Quick and dirty

In your entity, do this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupeDossier", mappedBy="test")
 */
private $groupeDossiers;

public function getGroupesDossierSeparated() {
    $result = ['assure'=>[], 'tiers'=>[]];
    foreach ($this->groupeDossiers as $d) {
        $result[$d->getType()][] = $d;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then, just with `$qb->leftJoin('d2.groupeDossiers')` you can use `getGroupesDossierSeparated()` to get the data you want.